# Expectation of r.v. in the proof of crossing number inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I was reading the proof of crossing number inequality and there was one step in the proof which I cannot prove rigorously.  Firstly, let me remind the definition of the crossing number and then I state the lemma and its proof. I will not write the whole proof since I understood it pretty well except one moment.

> **Definition** The crossing number of a graph $G=(V,E)$, denoted $\text{cr}(G)$, is the smallest integer $k$ such that we can draw $G$
> in the plane with $k$ edge crossings.

**Lemma (the crossing lemma)** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|E|\geq 4|V|$. Then $\text{cr}(G)\geq \frac{|E|^3}{64|V|^2}.$

*Proof.* Consider a drawing of $G$ with $\text{cr}(G)$ crossings. Set $p=\frac{4|V|}{|E|}$. The assumption of the lemma implies that $0<p\leq 1$. We remove every vertex of $V$ from the drawing with probability $1-p$ (together with the edges adjacent to the vertex).

More precisely, we consider the probability space $\Omega:=\{V': V'\subset V\}$ and we define probability as follows: $\mathbb{P}(V'):=p^{|V'|}(1-p)^{n-|V'|}$, where $n=|V|$.

We consider the following three random variables: $$\xi_1:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} \quad \text{defined as} \quad \xi_1(V'):=|V'|,$$ $$\xi_2:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} \quad \text{defined as} \quad \xi_2(V'):=|E'|,$$$$\xi_3:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} \quad \text{defined as} \quad \xi_3(V'):=\text{cr}(G'),$$ where $|E'|$ is the number of edges in the induced subgraph $G[V']$ and $\text{cr}(G')$ is crossing number of the induced subgraph $G':=G[V']$.

It is not difficult to compute that $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]=p|V|$ and $\mathbb{E}[\xi_2]=p^2|E|$. I computed them by the definition of expectation.

Can anyone show rigorously why $\mathbb{E}[\xi_3]\leq p^4\text{cr}(G)$? The rest of the proof makes sense to me.

I'd be very happy if someone can show the detailed proof of this inequality.

**EDIT:** For example, this is how I computed $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]$: since $\xi_1(V')=|V'|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{v_k}(V')$, where $$\mathbb{1}_{x}(V')=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x\in V' \\
0, & \text{if }x\notin V'
\end{cases}$$
By linearity of expectation we have $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}[1_{v_k}]=\sum_{k=1}^n p=p|V|.$
I wonder if it can be shown that $\mathbb{E}[\xi_3]\leq p^4\text{cr}(G)$ rigorously as I did?

Comment: You use linearity of expectation, as $\xi_3$ is the sum of $cr(G)$ Bernoulli random variable. Fix a drawing of $G$ minimising the number of crossing. Given a crossing in $G$, the crossing 'survives' in $G'$ if the two edges are still in $G'$, hence if all 4 vertices are not deleted, which happen with probability $p^4$. hence $cr(G')$ is at most $cr(G) p^4$

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues, Thanks for your comment but I am familiar with that "intuitive" reasoning. Literally the same reasonings are given in the books of Tao-Vu "Additive Combinatorics" and Adam Sheffer "Polynomial method and incidence theory" which I am reading. But it does not make sense to me. That is why I created this post to see the rigorous explanation which is given using the definition of expectation.

Comment: It takes a while to digest the proof. Let me see if I can get the hang of it.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, by rigorous I mean what I did in the edit. Please take a look. By the way, I am planning to start bounty on this question.

Comment: The "rigorous" version of the argument is the same as the one in your edit, just summing over all 4-tuples $(i, j, k, l)$ where $i < j$, $i < k < l$, and the edges $i-j$ and $k-l$ have a crossing in $G$. Maybe you could explain where you're getting stuck?

Comment: @Adam, thanks a lot for your attention to my question! I posted an answer (though I am not sure that it's correct). This is too long for comment and that's why I wrote it as a separate answer. So if you get a chance please take a look.

Comment: Looks good to me; you can't have an edge crossing on three vertices because it only counts as a crossing when the intersection point isn't a vertex. (Or on two vertices, because then you'd just have the same edge twice.)

Comment: @Adam, Dear Adam! I think you misunderstood my question. Please take a look at my question in the answer. I also attached a picture.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was thinking of the rectilinear crossing number. Misha's picture is correct; if there's a crossing on three vertices, you can untangle the loop, though I agree proving this rigorously is trickier.

Comment: @Adam, I am wondering can you prove it rigorously? The bounty is still active

Comment: @Adam, I updated my answer. If you get a chance, then please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my reasoning: so we have a r.v. $\xi_3(V')=\text{cr}(G[V'])$. Consider the drawing of $G$ which has minimal  number of edge crossings. In this drawing, we consider the induced subgraph $G[V']$. Obviously, $$\xi_3(V')\leq \#\left\{\{\{x,y\},\{z,w\}\}:x,y,z,w\in V',\ xy,zw\in E,\ xy\cap zw=\varnothing,\  xy \  \text{and} \ zw \ \text{have crossing}\right\}$$ It is not difficult to see that RHS is $$\frac{1}{8}\#\{(x,y,z,w)\in (V')^4:xy,zw\in E,\ xy\cap  zw=\varnothing,\ xy \ \text{and} \ zw \ \text{have crossing}\}.$$
Of course, here we assume that no edge crossing comes from three vertices (but I don't know how to prove it yet) and the notation $xy\cap zw=\varnothing$ means that $\{x,y\}\cap \{z,w\}=\varnothing$.

Taking expectation, have

$$\mathbb{E}[\xi_3]\leq \frac{1}{8}\sum_{\cdots}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_x]\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_y]\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_z]\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_w]=\frac{p^4}{8}\sum_{\cdots}1=p^4\text{cr}(G).$$

**UPD.** If we consider an optimal drawing of $G$ which has minimal number of edge crossings, then why we cannot have the following situation? More precisely, why edge crossing cannot arise from three points?

Suppose we have such a situation (see the picture below). So we have a crossing of blue and red edges. One can untangle it (see the picture on the right). Even in that case blue and red edges touch each other in a point which I denoted as $i$. But they should not touch each other at all. That is my concern.

[image]

Comment: Because https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pB4c.png.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I actually considered this situation as well. But in that case you have a touching point which arises from blue and red edges.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, can you help me please?

Comment: So move the curves apart a little locally.

Comment: I know this intuitively. But a natural question arises: if you move these edges apart a little locally, you need to be sure that they do not intersect with any other edges.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I am wondering do you know how to justify this "local separation" in a rigorous way?